# insert object in selected linq array

Tags: asp.net, linq, c#-4.0

I implemented the following method to get array of departments to bind to dropdownlist

```
public object[] GetDepartmentOptions()
{
   var departments = from p in context.per_Departments
                     where p.active == true
                     select new { DisplayText = p.departmentNameEn, 
                                  Value = p.departmentId };
   return departments.ToArray();
}
```

I would like to insert object in this array before bind it

```
object =new { DisplayText = "Choose", Value = 0 };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason it works only if your first sequence is the "choose" sequence:

```
    var first = new[] { new { DisplayText = "Choose", Value = 0 } };
    return first.Concat(departments).ToArray();
```